# Select both uppercase and lowercase from column

Tags: sql, pdo

I was wondering how I could get both uppercase and lowercase  from a sql query.

I've got lets say these values in my database.

```
John
Marco
jason
nico
```

So I would like to get both John and jason as a result.
At the moment I am searching with:

```
$pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'J%'");
```

However this only gives me John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE 'J%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your user table's name column isn't set to use case sensitivity. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html